# Empty the InputStream (of a Socket)

Tags: java, sockets, io

Some facts:
- My application is the client.
- I have a `Socket` pool.
- Multiple `Thread`s use this pool.
- Each `Thread` can timeout.
- On timeout, the `Socket` is returned to the pool, even if no reply was read from the server.

The problem:
On timeout, chances are that the next `Thread` that uses this `Socket` will have to read some old message (which was sent by the server after the Socket was returned).

The question:
What's the best way to "purge" the `InputStream` of a `Socket` before use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your I/O protocol did not complete normally, the best solution is to close offending I/O channel, remove it from the pool, open a new connection and add it to the pool.

For that to work, both Client and Server should be prepared for this eventuality by providing a method that confirms the other end liveness.

Comment: Even when the server is being slow for a few seconds only (and the connection is actually fine, processing is just slow)?

Comment: @Andrew.  The problem is, you never know where your previous thread has left off, so you don't know how to properly fast-forward to a known state.  Choosing appropriate timeouts is a black art of the network programming/maintenance and is the reason why network consultants (who know their stuff) are paid big $$ and worth every penny of it.